# Running another application inside a picturebox

Tags: vb.net, process

This is the sample code that I used to run another application inside a picturebox:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> Public Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hwndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hwndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Process1 As New Process
        Process1.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
        Process1.Start()

        Do Until Process1.WaitForInputIdle = True
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        SetParent(Process1.MainWindowHandle, PictureBox1.Handle)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thus, I was able to host another application inside my VB2010 WindowsForm and it works fine. But the problem is, in Windows7, Windows would ask for the permission(whether you want to allow the EXE to run or not). After clicking the "Allow" button, the exe application would open on it's own window rather than as a child of the PictureBox

I think when Windows asks for the permission, it is skipping the SetParent() API call. I really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks :)

Comment: There are plenty of limitations to this hack, the only reason it works at all is to provide compatibility for Windows 3.x programs. Plenty of other issues, well demonstrated by Adobe software running in a browser tab.  One such limitation is that a non-elevated process is not permitted to hijack the window of an elevated one.  You'll have to get yourself elevated first.

Comment: @HansPassant It doesn't work either when elevating the hosting process.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried using this line: `Process1.startInfo.Verb = "runas"`. But that's also not showing any luck. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in posting the solution. EdgeMeal from VBForums.com had helped me in finding a workaround to this issue. You could view the details here: [thread at vbforums.com](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?687825-RESOLVED-Running-another-application-inside-a-picturebox-issue-with-Windows7-permission)

And for elevating the permission, that is to ask for the Admin permission when the application starts, we need to change the `requestedExecutionLevel` value. To change this, goto the project properties(Project menu -->  Properties). Then from the `Application` tab, click on the `View Windows Settings` button. This will open the `app.manifest` file. In this, change the following line(uncommented line):

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This will ask the Admin permission whenever you run the application. Even when you run it from IDE, it will ask for re-opening the IDE with the Admin privilege.

BTW, I assumed that you would be using VB2010. The above steps are for VB2010(not sure whether it would be same for other versions also).

Hope it helps to someone who is fighting with the same issue. :)

Comment: Interesting idea; wondering what practical application this could be used for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following statement between `Do Until` and `SetParent`:

> System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)