# Winform showing another application inside a PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

First, I would like to state that I understand that my problem is similar to [Running another application inside a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006392/running-another-application-inside-a-picturebox), however my application runs the .exe just fine it instead will not always nest it inside the picturebox.

In my c# winforms application I am attempting to run the calc.exe inside a PictureBox, however about 75% of the time my application just runs the calc.exe as its own window.

My code is below.

```
enter code hereprivate void Preview_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveWindows_ListBox.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is no Window selected to take a picture of.", "Insufficient Data");
            return;
        }
        Process p = Process.Start("calc.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, ViewingScreen_PictureBox.Handle);
    }
```

From my understanding of what I am trying to do I am starting the  calc.exe application that is native to windows, then telling my application to wait for the calculator to initialize its self then tell the calculator that the picturebox is the parent of the calculator.

That leaves my question, is there something that I am missing which is making it so that my application doesn't set the calculator inside the picturebox 100% of the time?

Thank you for the help in advance.

P.S. I have tried to adjust the Thread.Sleep to give my application more and less time than what it has now with no change in behavior.

Comment: I'm assuming SetParent does some P/Invoke, have you tried seeing what the last error code is after the call? Depending on the return type, you may need to set some additional flags in the DllImport attribute.

Comment: To the poster who marked this question down I would love to get some feedback as to why this was marked down so that I may better improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several caveats in your code:

1. Your call to WaitForInputIdle should check the return value. The idle state is reached only when the call returns true (see MSDN).
2. Even if the idle state has been reached, the p.MainWindowHandle may return zero. A busy-waiting loop can wait for the handle to become non-zero. Not nice, but sufficient here to show the principle.  A diagnostic counter ctr shows how often the loop has been accessed.
3. The following code should bind the calculator reliably to the picture box, and additionally the picBox is resized to the calculators size, such that always the whole calculator is visible, regardless of the picBox's initial size.

   ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPthWndNewParent);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
   private struct RECT { public int Left; public int Top; public int Right; public int Bottom; }
   ```

static int ctr = 0;

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = Process.Start("calc.exe");
    IntPtr h = IntPtr.Zero;

    //Wait for calc.exe to establish
    while ((h = p.MainWindowHandle) == IntPtr.Zero)
        ctr++;

    //Get size of calculator
    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(h, out r);

    //width and height of the calculator
    int calcWidth = r.Right - r.Left;
    int calcHeight = r.Bottom - r.Top;

    //bind calculator to pictureBox
    SetParent(h, pictureBox1.Handle);

    //move calcusator to upper left corner of picturebox
    MoveWindow(h, 0, 0, calcWidth, calcHeight, true);

    //resize pictureBox to Calculator size
    Size newPicBoxSize = new Size(calcWidth, calcHeight);
    pictureBox1.Size = newPicBoxSize;
}
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful. The calc.exe was just for me trying to prove to myself a proof of concept that it could be done the way I thought it could.   Thank you for the quick feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Process p = new Process();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    private void Preview_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p = Process.Start("calc.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, ViewingScreen_PictureBox.Handle);
        MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 230, 320, true);
    }
```